# How do I move items in the Applications (or Main) Menu Around?

Tags: 12.10, appmenu, alacarte

I'm running **12.10** and in 12.04 I was able to move the items (into other categories than where they're presently situated) in the *applications menu* by means of moving them in the application, *main menu*.

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu, I think. [I have a highly customised desktop it looks almost identical to Mac OS X]

Comment: Do you mean Unity? With Dash, Launcher, panel, globalmenu? So you're talking about rearranging the items in the Dash?

Comment: No I'm using Cairo-Dock and its 'Application Menu' is what I'm talking about

Comment: So what's your exact problem? Do you want to know the name of the program that calls itself "main menu" or doesn't it work anymore since 12.10?

Comment: It works, it opens and everything is working fine except in 12.10 I can't move the application launchers around and place them under the title I would like them to be under.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6748/discussion-between-jp-wann-and-brenton-horne)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--- this problem was solved in the chat ---

The problem was that the file **/home/brentonhorne/.config/menus/applications.menu** wasn't writable by the standard user. brentonhorne is the standard user on this system, for everyone reading this, you'll have to exchange this username of course.

The problem was fixed by setting the permissions of the .config folder and all of it's subfolders as they should be (owned by the user, readable and writable by the owner) - again for everyone else, you'll have to insert your own username for brentonhorne.

```
sudo chown -R brentonhorne:brentonhorne /home/brentonhorne/.config && sudo chmod u+rw /home/brentonhorne/.config
```