# How can I move items in Alacarte?

Tags: 15.04, alacarte

I would like to be able to move (i.e., drag) application launchers from menu to menu within Alacarte, but for whatever reason I cannot. I realize this question is basically identical to a [previous question of mine](https://askubuntu.com/q/229349/93125) but this time I am on 15.04 and I tried the answer that worked for me last time, namely, running:

```
sudo chown -R fusion809:fusion809 /home/fusion809/.config && sudo chmod u+rw /home/fusion809/.config
```

(keeping in mind my username has changed to fusion809). But I still cannot drag items in Alacarte from menu to menu like I used to be able to.