# From where are application icons for the LXDE menu loaded?

Tags: menu, lxde

I would like to customize the LXDE menu to my liking, and I've been trying to so with Alacarte with some, minor success (but a few problems, e.g., see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634039/how-can-i-move-items-in-alacarte) of mine). Namely I can seem to add items to submenus (i.e., menus within the major menus like `Science`). But something I've noticed is that there are a lot more items in the menus than that shown in Alacarte. Take, for example the `Other` menu and its contents.

How Alacarte displays the `Other` menu:
[image]

compared to an incredibly long list in the LXDE menu (I tried several times using `Prnt Scr` to take a screenshot of the menu but for whatever reason it won't work while the LXDE menu is open; this menu is found under the Tux icon in the top left-hand corner) under `Other`, including:

- Amazon
- Amule
- Anjuta
- Advanced Package Manager (text)
- Atom
  ...

My `Office` is also giving me grief. I remove several menu items in Alacarte, moving them into submenus within the `Office` yet they still appear in the LXDE menu.

Alacarte menu:
    [image]

LXDE menu:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sadly, I deleted the others menu before I saw this comment. But I am still getting an error with my office menu. So I added it to my question.